# Impact of Daemon Thread Or Normal Thread When Application is Running in Development mode

Tags: java, multithreading, akka, quartz-scheduler, playframework-2.3

What is the impact for using Daemon threads or Normal Threads in my
**Play Application**. I am having some Akka Scheduler, and Quarts Schedulers. These are being start When Application start. My App is running in Dev mode, and whenever i made changes to my Source Code, it restart's / Auto Reload application that **Cause Thread DeadLock**. What is the best way to stopping these Threads.

> 1. Is it good to use Daemon Threads here ?
> 2. Will System.exit(0) will be Useful here ?
> 3. Is any Other way to stopping these running/waiting threads that are sleeping for a particular time in scheduling ?

I'm trying to do something like:

> ```
> @Override
> public void onStart(Application app) {
> Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(Duration.create(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), Duration.create(60000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
>   () -> {
>   String url = Play.application().configuration().getString("localloadbalancer.ip");
>   url = url + "initCallOut";
>   Logger.info("Calling initcall from global.java::" + url);
>   HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
>   HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
>   try {
>   HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
>   int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
>   Logger.info("Status Code::" + statusCode);
>   if (statusCode == 200) {
>    //Do stuff here
>   } else {
>    //retry
>   }
>   } catch (IOException ex) {
>   Logger.error("Error in Initcall::" + ex.getMessage());
>   }
>   }, Akka.system().dispatcher());
>
>   // Quartz scheduler starting here
>
>   try {
>    QuartzScheduler.startScheduler();
>   }
>   catch (Exception ex){
>    System.out.println("Scheduler Exception::"+ex.getMessage());
>   }
>   }
> ```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "impact".  There is only one difference between a daemon thread and a normal thread:  The existence of a normal, running thread will prevent the JVM from shutting itself down, but the existence of a running daemon thread will not.  `System.exit()` will _force_ the JVM to shut down regardless of whether any normal threads are running or not.

Comment: yeah, but it's regarding my Play Framework application running in Dev mode. It always re starts application, so when it start again the threads get stuck if they were waiting on previous state before re loading .

Comment: @AshishRatan do you have any update on this?

Comment: @Kainix Nope. Not yet.